# Switch icu4c version (Homebrew)

Tags: composer-php, homebrew, laravel-valet, homebrew-cask, icu4c

When running composer commands I get an error and it seems I have to change the icu4c version. (At the moment I need a composer command to re(install) - `composer global require weprovide/valet-plus`) However, when I try to change it using the steps below I get errors.

Error when running composer command (globally):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
[2]    12103 abort      composer global require weprovide/valet-plus
```

Steps taken to change icu4c version:

```
$ cd $(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
$ git checkout 2a369a82c7f5b3b2ab2704ff0796635514aae955
$ brew reinstall ./icu4c.rb
```

Error when reinstall icu4c.rb:

```
Error: Failed to load cask: ./icu4c.rb
Cask 'icu4c' is unreadable: wrong constant name #<Class:0x00007fba9a59e168>
Warning: Treating ./icu4c.rb as a formula.
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/icu4c/manifests/67.1
##O#- #                                                                       
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
Error: Failed to download resource "icu4c_bottle_manifest"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/icu4c/manifests/67.1
```

Anyone who knows how to tackle this? I guess version 67.1 is needed for everything to work. Please let me know if you know anything that might be helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share more details. Where do you run "Composer commands" in the given set of commands and messages?

Comment: I need composer commands to run in Valet. And at the moment I need it to (re)install Valet (composer global require weprovide/valet-plus), therefore I need to run the composer command globally. Does these details give enough perspective?

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the question by editing it. Also, please share which errors occur, and how you run these commands

Comment: Thanks, done! Please let me know is something is still missing.